Saving HTML with Jinja (or Django Template Language) into the Sqlite model
I am trying to save the HTML with Jinja output into an Sqlite model.
I want the rendered output (without curly braces {} or %% signs) to be saved into the model.
I have no idea on how to format it.
Tried the render_to_string function but it does not seem an appropriate solution.
Thank you.

We use render_to_string, why not?
class MyModel(models.Model):
    template = 'myapp/mymodel_template.html'
    ...

    ...
    rendered = models.TextField(_('Rendered context'), blank=True, default='')
    # we use RichTextUploadingFieldWidget to edit this field, if it needed.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.rendered:
            self.rendered = render_to_string(self.template, self.context)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

self.template - attribute from class, contains template.
self.context - some method or field with dict data, which provide context for render.
